# Connect to DSL modem without using ethernet cable

Tags: wireless-router, routing, dsl-modem

I have a Dsl modem connecting to isp
Inside it is a wireless linksys wrt router.
my computer is a mac.
at the moment to check the config of the dsl modem I have to use ethernet cable to switch port.
I want to be able to connect to the dsl via the wireless connection. Should I be setting up a static route on the mac or on the router?
Thanks

Comment: No. As long as you know the ip of the router, just go to http://<ip-of-router> in your browser or use ssh <ip-of-router>.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by router configuration.

At the first, you have to connect to your router by cable and go to the security tab then you should looking for the option that mean "Allow config the router via wireless connection". However, It's better that you just config router via cable because of security reason.

I didn't know your router model so you should find that option or such as that in user manual.